# SCROLL JAVASCRIPT Skip one image and go to the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using javascript scroll plugin to scroll full page image horizontally. Now what I want is when I click down arrow it skips the next slide and moves to the third one by just passing by the second one.
How can I do that?

Comment: Often these plugins will have an API that supports programmatic access to features. What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html and improve with simply javascript.

To the button, element, arrow or something that will be clicked, but recommend using a (hyperlink):

```
<a href="#go-to-text">Go to text</a>
```

For the text that will receive focus after clicked

```
<div id="go-to-text">
your text
</div>
```

To understand The element A, with the attribute href starting with #, lead to another element with the same id, which need not contain the #.

The element has id # + of another html element
Element that receives focus has the ID referring to the element